# Is it possible to overline labels / text / strings in QGIS 3.x?

Tags: qgis, labeling, text, string

I would like to overline the denominator in these fractions.

[image: Voters over Registered = Turnout]

Underlining the numerator would result in too short a line when the numerator is shorter than the denominator.

The numbers in this image are 3 rule-based labels, placed in relation to each other and the bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share how you've configured your rule-based labels to appear in those exact positions relative to each other? (did you use specific offsets?) Since you want these to be separate labels with separate colours, depending on how you've set them up, you could look into using geometry generator to generate a line in that specific position between the two labels.

But to respond to one of your issues, if you want to underline the numerator to match the length of the denominator, you can use `rpad()` or `lpad()` in the expression for the numerator to pad out its length with blank spaces and extend the underline.

For example, if your numerator value is `"numerator"`, and you want the underline to match the length of the corresponding denominator value (`"denominator"`), you can try the following:

`rpad("numerator",length("denominator"),' ')`

[image]

However, it doesn't look that great, because the underline is placed very cloes to the text it's applied to. Additionally, with variable-width typefaces, the actual length of the denominator text on screen/paper may still be a bit longer than the numerator + whitespace padding.

Comment: Thank you very much. Although it might not "look that great" as you put it, it's not bad at all. Since it's for a map still in design stage it will do for the time being.

If you don't mind, I'd like to leave the question unanswered for maybe a couple more weeks, just in case someone comes up with another alternative. Then I'll mark it as answered.

TY again!\

Comment: About the positioning of the labels, it's exactly as you figured it out, i.e. specific offsets.
Not that elegant, but gets the job done with QGIS's diagrams engine.